# Angular website path not working properly

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, web-hosting

I have an angular website I am attempting to host on heroku. Here is my server.js file showing the path I want to use.
[Server.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZDiD.png)

However, I get this error after build.
[Heroku Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAQH0.png)

Here is my applications directories.
[App setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7hJZ.png)

This is the first time I have tried to host a angular site so I am not very well versed. But from what I can tell I want the path to the index.html file in my dist/dashboard directory. Which seems to be what is a happening. I have tried removing the "__dirname" however this doesnt work either. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
heres my package.json

```
{
"name": "dashboard",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"“heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^9.0.7",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"enhanced-resolve": "^4.3.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"highcharts": "^8.1.2",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"typescript": "~3.7.5",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
"@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.3",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~5.18.0",
"typescript": "~3.7.5"
},
"engines": {
"node": "12.16.1",
"npm": "6.13.4"
}
```

}

Comment: could you provide your package.json?

Comment: @Andrei I added my package.json

Comment: Have you tried adding some console logging into the express part? Maybe helps you find out why it cannot find the file.

https://stackfame.com/list-all-files-in-a-directory-nodejs

Comment: There is also the option to solve hosting of a compiled app by using a one-line php file: https://medium.com/@winnieliang/how-to-run-a-simple-html-css-javascript-application-on-heroku-4e664c541b0b

Answer (score 0):

When removing the dirname, did you define the server.js file like the script below? Also edit the *package.json* file: **“heroku-postbuild** to **heroku-postbuild**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./dist/dashboard'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/dashboard/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: The dist directory is being searched within the application directory. Therefore, force it to return to a directory above and locate the folder dist: *./dist*